# PhpMailer 2 раза шлёт письмо, вместо одного

Tags: php, phpmailer

Есть форма восстановления пароля значит. Поле для емайла, капча гугла, и кнопка.
Ввожу емайл, прохожу капчу и жму на кнопку, идёт проверка -  если емайл есть в базе отсылаю на почту пароль, иначе ошибка.
Для отправки письма использую PhpMailer. Проблема: письмо отправляется 2 раза.
Как сделать, чтобы 1 раз отправлялось письмо?

Отправка:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'xxxx@yandex.ru';
$mail->Password = 'xxx';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->setFrom('xxxx@yandex.ru', 'Hmm');

$mail->addAddress($user[0]['email'], $user[0]['login']);

$mail->Subject = 'Востановление пароля';

$body = "<p><strong>Приветствую тебя.</strong></p>";
$body .= "Твой логин - ".$user[0]['login'].", пароль - ".$user[0]['password']." .";
$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->send();

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
   echo "success";
}
```

Comment: Не писать два раза `$mail->send()`. Это должно быть очевидно

Answer (score 0):

Насколько помню - сам наступил в своё время на эти грабли. У Вас в коде действительно два раза вызывается метод send():

```
... 

// $mail->send(); первая отправка происходит здесь. закомментировать 

if (!$mail->send()) { // а вторая - здесь 
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

так что комментируйте строку с первым вызовом $mail->send() - и будет Вам счастье)